# Slanted DIv not showing

Tags: html, css

Hi guys i am trying to recrate a slanted div such as [This](http://gt3demo.com/html/timber/?_ga=2.257578763.1059025295.1507829688-2135208213.1507829688)
 But i cant seem to get the picture to show at all :

HTML:

```
<div class="headerLine">

</div>
```

css:

```
.headerLine{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url("../Images/back1.jpg"); 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.headerLine:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* background: url(../images/sliderL.png) center center no-repeat; */
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: 150px solid white;
    border-left: 3000px solid transparent;
}
```

Any help on creating a div which is slanted as the example posted above, the very first div, would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue here is `height: 100%` in the div. It's the parent of that element so what is the parent's height set to? If it's not set to anything then the browser has nothing to reference.

You can use vh (view height) to work around this.

[SEE CODEPEN EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/DollarChills/pen/oGPPZg)

Answer (score 0):

As you mention the background is not showing and the reason I got is that u haven't placed any content inside the div so how some background would appear.

You can place some content or can use some static height like 100vh.

```
[SEE THE EXAMPLE][1]




[1]: https://codepen.io/hardenrahul/pen/NaLeNv
```